# Angular ngOnChanges not being triggered when parent property changing

Tags: angular

so I have a child component which i pass a User prop as follows:

```
 <user-profile-stage-five
    [User]="User"
    (goToStage)="changeSlide($event)"
  ></user-profile-stage-five>
```

And another component which can update the User prop in the parent as follows:

```
  <user-profile-stage-zero
    [User]="User"
    (goToStage)="changeSlide($event)"
    (updateUserProfile)="onUpdateUserProfile($event)"
  ></user-profile-stage-zero>
```

Here is the parent component:

```
  public onUpdateUserProfile(user: User): void {
    this.User = user;
    console.log(this.User.profile);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

However the User prop is not changing in the child component:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('stage 5 changes: ', changes); // not being triggered when User changes in parent 
  }
```

I really cannot understand why the User prop is not changing in the child component, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the reason why my User prop was not changing in the child component had to do with how I accessed the User property. Previously I accessed it like

```
this.profileProvider.getUserProfile(this.userId)
   .get()
   .then(res => {
      this.User = res.data() as User;
});
```

However this seems to be a static copy of the User. I changed to the following:

```
this.user$ = this.getUser();

public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.profileProvider.getUser();
}

// profile provider

    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }),
    );

  // returns user as an observable
  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.user$;
  }
```

I then used an async pipe to pass the user$ property to the child components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an immutable object inorder to trigger Angular Change Detection.

```
public onUpdateUserProfile(user: User): void {
    this.User = {...user};
    console.log(this.User.profile);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is causing my app to crash - it looks to be creating recursion - I tried taking out the changeDetector too

Comment: can you please create stackblitz for this.